# Filter syntax for Dimensions & Weight?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, filter

Is there comparable syntax to display dimension and weight filter settings from Commerce similar to those for currency eg: `{{ variant.price|currency('CAD') }}`? Couldn't see any info on this in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no filter but you can access the units of measurement from your settings, and display the measurement:

```
{% set weightUnits = craft.commerce.settings.weightUnits %}
{% set dimensionUnits = craft.commerce.settings.dimensionUnits %}


{{ variant.weight }} {{ weightUnits }} // 10 mm
```

Comment: Thx Luke. That'll work for me.